# How do I cascade animations in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, cascade, infinite-loop

I've created 3 div elements and I need a set of images to pass through the boxes shifting one by one by displaying an image in one box, then the next, then the next every 5 seconds on an infinite loop.

I would like the images to fade out one after the other (half a second gap before firing the next box fadeout) so it looks like they are cascade fading, I would like the fadeout to last for a second, then have the new image within that box to fade in, taking about a second to do so, and the next box triggering a fade in with a half second gap.

I've got them looping, but not cascading, can someone provide me with a solution to the problem? Below is my current code :

```
<div id="box1"></div><div id="box2"></div><div id="box3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var test = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg'];
function loopImages()
{
    // swap image positions in array
    var fimg = test.shift();
    test.push(fimg);
    for (a in test) {
        var newimage = $('<img />').attr('src',test[a]);
        var currbox = $('#box' + (Math.floor(a)+1));
        //first fade out
        currbox.find('img').fadeTo('slow',0);
        // then add new image
        currbox.empty().append(newimage);   
    }
    // loop every 5 seconds
    setTimeout("loopImages()",5000);
}
loopImages();
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var test = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg'];
function loopImages() {
    var fimg = test.shift();
    test.push(fimg);
    $.each(test, function(i, img) {
        var newimage = $('<img />').attr('src',img);
        $('#box' + (i+1)).find('img').delay(i*1000).fadeTo('slow',0, function() {
          $(this).html(newimage); //shortcut for .empty().append()
        });
    });
    setTimeout(loopImages, 5000);
}
$(loopImages);
```

Using [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and multiplying by the index you're at in the array, your animations will be staggered.  Also, you want to perform your operations for changing after the fade has completed I'm guessing, so do that in the [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) callback.

Other changes: running `loopImages` when the document's ready, passing a reference (not a string) to [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), and using a traditional `for` loop to *iterate* over an array (don't use a `for...in` here, it's for *enumeration*).

Comment: Hi Nick, I've tried that example, but it seems the first two boxes are wiped out after the first loop, it's only the third box that loops, and it doesn't fade, it just flips between the images

Comment: @Paul - my fault, it's the `curbox` reference that's shared, try the updated code above.

Comment: Nick, Thanks for that, it definitely helped towards sorting things out, there was a strange bug though, it seems that by the time the image has faded and the callback is fired, the newimage variable has been over-written and is always the result of the very last loop (i==test.length) so, to overcome the problem, I created an array at the start of the script (lets call it testimages) and stored $('<img />').attr('src',test[i]) in testimages[i] . I'll post my solution, it's a bit of an ugly hack, but seems to work smoothly

Comment: @Paul - doh, same issues as before...see my update above to address that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your images in HTML first, then use something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.fadeImages = function(repeatTime, timeBetweenBoxes, boxExistanceTime) {
        var images = this.children('img').hide();
        runFade = function() {
            images.each(function(i) {
                var image = this;
                window.setTimeout(function() { $(image).fadeIn();  }, i * timeBetweenBoxes);
                window.setTimeout(function() { $(image).fadeOut(); }, i * timeBetweenBoxes + boxExistanceTime);
            });
        };
        window.setInterval(runFade, repeatTime);
        runFade();
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#box1,#box2,#box3').fadeImages(5000, 1000, 1100);
});
```

Tweak the times in the function call for the desired result.

**Edit:** added `return this;` to make it support chaining.

Comment: jsfiddle link... instead of images, I've used yellow divs. http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/wbhFK/

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a bit of an ugly hack to Nick's great solution so that it stopped the bug of the newimage variable being over-written and always being the result of the very last loop (i==test.length) which seemed to wipe out all images apart from the last one. If someone has a neater solution than my hack, feel free to post!

```
<div id="box1"><img src="1.jpg" /></div><div id="box2"><img src="2.jpg" /></div><div id="box3"><img src="3.jpg" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var test = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
var imagearr = [];
function loopImages() {
    var fimg = test.pop();
    test.unshift(fimg);
    for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
        var container = '#box' + (i+1);
        imagearr[i] = $(container);
        imagearr[i].find('img').data('count',i).delay(i*400).fadeTo('fast',0, function() {
          var i = $(this).data('count');
          var suffix = (i == 0) ? '' : '_small';
          var newimage = $('<img />').attr('src',test[i]);
          imagearr[i].html(newimage);
          newimage.css('opacity',0).fadeTo('slow',1);
        });
    }
    setTimeout(loopImages, 1000 * test.length + 3000);
}
$(loopImages);
//]]>
</script>
```